# Distribution of $\min(X_1+X_2+X_3,X_2+X_3+X_4,X_3+X_4+X_5,X_4+X_5+X_6)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, self-learning

Let $X_{i}\,(i=1,2,3,4,5,6)$ be i.i.d. continuous random variables with distribution $F( \cdot )$ and density $f( \cdot )$. What will be the distribution of $$\min(X_1+X_2+X_3,~ X_2+X_3+X_4,~ X_3+X_4+X_5,~ X_4+X_5+X_6)~?$$

Here is my attempt-

Let $W=\min(X_1+X_2+X_3,X_2+X_3+X_4,X_3+X_4+X_5,X_4+X_5+X_6)$. We need to find $P(W\leq w)$. Let $X_2 = x_2,X_3=x_3,X_4=x_4,X_5=x_5$. Then, the problem reduces to

$$P\left( \begin{aligned}
&X_1 \leq w-x_2-x_3, \\
&x_2+x_3+x_4\leq w, \\
&x_3+x_4+x_5\leq w, \\
&X_6\leq w-x_4-x_5
\end{aligned}~\middle|~ \begin{aligned}
X_2 &= x_2, \\
X_3 &= x_3, \\
X_4 &= x_4, \\
X_5 &=x_5 
\end{aligned}\right)~$$

Since all $X_i$ are independent, then we can write the above expression as

$$P(X_1\leq w-x_2-x_3) \cdot P(X_6\leq w-x_4-x_5)$$ 
subject to the limits 
$$x_2+x_3+x_4\leq w,x_3+x_4+x_5\leq w~.$$

Is my approach correct?

Comment: You should go for finding $P(W>w)$ (not $P(W\leq w)$). Note that $P(\min(X,Y)>w)=P(X>w,Y>w)$ which is better to handle than $P(W\leq w)=P(X\leq w\text{ or }Y\leq w)$.

Comment: @drhab I get your point. But I'm a little confused about the limits of the integrals. Can you please help me out with that?